# How can I pull data from two rows in csv with one being the header and other the data?

Tags: python, csv, jython

I have a CSV sheet with two rows of data in rows 4 and 5. Row 4 has the titles and row 5 has the corresponding data for it. How do I pull data and put it in another CSV sheet? The title row has formatting similar to

```
Title_XYZ[0].XXX_YYY_Record.XXX_YYY.AAA 
Title_XYZ[0].XXX_YYY_Record.XXX_YYY.BBB
Title_XYZ[1].XXX_YYY_Record.XXX_YYY.AAA 
Title_XYZ[1].XXX_YYY_Record.XXX_YYY.BBB
Title_XYZ[2].XXX_YYY_Record.XXX_YYY.AAA 
Title_XYZ[2].XXX_YYY_Record.XXX_YYY.BBB
```

with the number in the [] changing with every new cell? I can't use pandas.

I have tried reading the files using import CSV, pulling the file to read, and using

```
header = lines[4].split(',')
```

to grab data and write a new CSV file using that but that just copies and paste the data instead of assigning AAA with AAA and BBB with BBB.

The data looks something like this:

| Title_XYZ[0].XXX_YYY_Record.XXX_YYY.AAA | Title_XYZ[0].XXX_YYY_Record.XXX_YYY.BBB | Title_XYZ[1].XXX_YYY_Record.XXX_YYY.AAA | Title_XYZ[1].XXX_YYY_Record.XXX_YYY.BBB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |

And the output should look like

| AAA | BBB |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 13 |
| 14 | 15 |

Comment: would you pls post the output you are expecting? it's hard to get from the question.

Comment: I added some sample data with sample output

Comment: You say you can't use pandas, why? Is this a homework assignment? How generic does your solution need to be? Do all your .csv files consist of the exact same format and number of lines, or do you need to process files of varying sized, with different numbers of columns and rows encoded in the same fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import re
data="""
Title_XYZ[0].XXX_YYY_Record.XXX_YYY.AAA Title_XYZ[0].XXX_YYY_Record.XXX_YYY.BBB Title_XYZ[1].XXX_YYY_Record.XXX_YYY.AAA Title_XYZ[1].XXX_YYY_Record.XXX_YYY.BBB
12  13  14  15
"""
records = []
regex = r"(?:(?P<AAA>\d+)\s(?P<BBB>\d+)){1,2}"
for match in re.finditer(regex, data):
        records.append(match.groupdict())

pd.DataFrame(records)
```

[image]